# Can you make moose bacon?

Tags: bacon, moose

I like moose and I like bacon. Is it possible to make moose bacon? How is the moose belly?

Answer (score 10):

Moose have bellies, so there is no reason that you can't make moose bacon.  If you like moose, there is a high likelihood you will like moose bacon.  Whether or not other people like it or not is not really something we address on this site.  I would say, give it a go and report back.  [Here is a brief conversation about moose bacon.](http://forums.outdoorsdirectory.com/showthread.php/112763-Moose-bacon-recipes)  It might help.

Comment: "Here is a brief conversation about moose bacon", I never thought I'd hear that phrase @moscafj!

Comment: And yet, here we have created another brief conversation about moose bacon.

Comment: A short conversation about a very long strip of bacon.